# Autocomplete Per-Character Usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I had a few questions related to the changes to the Google Maps/Routes/Places that happened a couple weeks ago

1. My app calls `places.PlacesService.GetAutocompletePredictions` and, at the moment, in the Google Cloud Platform, I can see my "request" usage. However the billing switched to "per-character" and I could not find my usage by that metric. Any idea how to view it?
2. Is there a way to see my usage for the past few months?
3. How does this "per-character" thing work? Is it the number of characters of the prediction that I pick or the number of characters predicted at the end of my pre-filled phrase? Google doesn't seem to want to make their pricing particularly clear

Comment: did you get more info about point 3?